# How to interpret TimeseriesModelFit parameters?

Tags: fitting, time-series

I have problems interpreting the parameters that follow using the TimeseriesModelFit command. The time series exists of twelve months and show a positive linear trend. Using TimeseriesModelFit it gives ARIMA 0,1,0. The process output is as follows:

```
tsm//Normal
```

gives

> ARIMAProcess[273., {}, 1, {}, 3505.09]

My question: how do I interpret these results? What does 273, {}, 1, and so on mean? How can I use these values to create a model? Ultimately, I would like to produce a function, such as y = ax + b, although probably another function applies as we're speaking about a random walk. I do not know how to interpret these results to create such a function.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs of [`ARIMAProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ARIMAProcess.html)?

Comment: Are you familiar with autoregressive models? Personally, I am not, but it seems to me that understanding these models is a precondition to being able to interpret the result of `TimeSeriesModelFit`.  If the gist of your question boils down to what these models are, then it's not a very good fit here ...

Comment: @corey979 Thanks for your comment! Yes, I have spent lots of hours on this page. However, it does not provide information about the interpretation of the process parameters, how to use them for building a model, or how to plot the model with the existing time series.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for your reply! I have some, but basic knowledge about AR models. It is just that I need to build a model, and acquiring these parameters so efficiently is amazing, but so far I have not found an option to translate them into a mathematical model, which is exactly what I need. E.g. communicating these parameters to others is not efficient. It would be better if I can communicate a model that they can use to predict future values.

Comment: [How to interpret ARIMA(0,1,0)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310353/how-to-interpret-arima0-1-0)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while it is a good question, it would be better asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/. Because there might be some resistance to answer there because it might look to CrossValidated that this is a *Mathematica* question, if you could possibly run the model in R (using the arima function) and also give those results, there would be a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: @TLP  Why didn’t you read the manual on page `ref/TimeSeriesModelFit` ?

Comment: @AlexTrounev thanks for your comment! It's naive to assume I did not consult the page you suggested. There, too, I did not find the exact interpretation. The answer garej has provided is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the reference anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kind of a comment because I see this topic has a bit unfriendly description in the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ARIMAProcess.html).
The meaning is as follows:

> ARIMAProcess[start, {AR}, D, {MA}, [Sigma]^2]

were `AR` stands for autoregressive process, `D` stands for difference and `MA` for moving average (those AR and MA could be matrices). `Sigma^2` stands for variance. Most confusing is `start`, but it is simply the starting value on vertical axis.

Hope that helps.